# What causes the following gaps?

Tags: graphics

I have tried to remove any possible white spaces by appending `%` but the gaps still exist. What causes these gaps?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(2\wd\IBox,2\ht\IBox)%
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}%
    \rput[bl](\wd\IBox,0){\psscalebox{-1 -1}{\usebox\IBox}}%
    \rput[bl](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox){\psscalebox{1 -1}{\usebox\IBox}}%
    \rput[bl](0,\ht\IBox){\psscalebox{-1 1}{\usebox\IBox}}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The bounding box info for the image says `0 0 100 100`, so the image is 100bp high. The default resolution for `dvips` is 600dpi; scaling to 50% makes for 416.66667 pixels, truncated to 416.

The height of the image is computed by TeX to be 50.1875pt, which is the same, but apparently EPS inclusion truncates, while rule positioning rounds. So if I compile

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,picture}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\usebox{\IBox}}
\the\ht\IBox
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I run instead

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips: { options: "-D 10000" }
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,picture}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-grid-100x100pt}}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\usebox{\IBox}}
\the\ht\IBox
\end{document}
```

I get a better filling at the top, worse on the side.

[image]

If I pass the EPS image through `eps2eps` so a hires bounding box is computed, I get in `example-grid-100x100pt-hires.eps` the prolog

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 100 100
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 99.600000 99.600000
```

Now the input

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,picture}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[hiresbb,scale=0.5]{example-grid-100x100pt-hires}}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\usebox{\IBox}}
\the\ht\IBox
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

No gap and the height is computed correctly.

Comment: Does `\includegraphics` use `hiresbb` by default?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot No: if you notice, the "good" example uses the key `hiresbb`

Comment: So, when do we need to use `hiresbb`? Is it a best practice to always use `hiresbb`?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot If the EPS file has no HiResBoundingBox information it's useless.

Comment: What option did you pass to `eps2eps` to avoid getting rastered output?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot I didn't pass any option

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with `pstricks`.  This seems to have to do with the image you're importing.

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\setlength{\fboxrule}{4pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\savebox\IBox{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=5.5]{example-grid-100x100pt}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(2\wd\IBox,2\ht\IBox)%
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}%
%    \rput[bl](\wd\IBox,0){\psscalebox{-1 -1}{\usebox\IBox}}%
%    \rput[bl](\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox){\psscalebox{1 -1}{\usebox\IBox}}%
%    \rput[bl](0,\ht\IBox){\psscalebox{-1 1}{\usebox{\IBox}}}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

From the output, it seems pretty clear that the white space you're getting is from the image itself that you're importing.

[image]